# Filling Array once worked, does not anymore (subscript out of range)

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have once worked to add/delete groups of rows (requirements).  I needed to modify the code so that if the 1st row of the group met certain criteria (i.e, the requirement was not one we wanted to consider), (1) we would not count it and (2), we would hide the group (current and subsequent 2 rows).  This all works fine.

The problem is that now that I incorporated these changes, I get an error in another section of the code and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.  I have stepped through this and am extremely frustrated.  I am reaching out for help, and am hoping someone can see my error(!)

We calculate the start and finish row numbers within a grouping, and store these calculations in Arrays called "Start" and "Finish."  I use the ReDim statement to initialize my arrays, because I thought that could be part of the problem, but no.

Any insight as to why my "subscripts are out of range" would be appreciated.  I have traced through the logic, investigated this error, and read about the syntax/usage of VBA arrays.  I don't know what else to do.  Thanks in advance.  Here are the relevant lines:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearOutline
    If Cells.EntireRow.Hidden Then Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Dim Start() As Integer
    Dim Finish() As Integer
    Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
    ReDim Start(0, 50)
    ReDim Finish(0, 50)
```

The following is embedded in logic that loops through all the rows in the spreadsheet:

```
i = 1

    For Row = 4 To Cells(1, 6).Value - 1
        If Begin Then
            If Cells(Row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then
                Start(i) = Row + 1
                j = Cells(Row, 2).Value
                Begin = False
            End If
        Else
            If Cells(Row, 2).Value = j + 1 Or Cells(Row, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 Then
                Finish(i) = Row - 1
                Begin = True
                i = i + 1
                Row = Row - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

The block I changed is as follows (code I added is last block where I attempt to hide rows).  It precedes the previous.  I am wondering how my change could have affect the above(?!)

```
   If Cells(Row, 5).Value = "Requirement" Then
        Range(Cells(Row, 4), Cells(Row, 4)).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        Rows(Row).Font.Bold = True
        Rows(Row).Font.Italic = False
        Rows(Row).Font.ColorIndex = 1 'Black
        If Cells(Row - 3, 4).Value = "" Then 'this is requirement #1
            Cells(Row, 4).Value = 1
            Else
            Cells(Row, 4).Value = Cells(Row - 3, 4).Value + 1
        End If

        p = Row
        q = p + 2
        Rows(p & ":" & q).Select
        If Cells(p, 19).Value = "4" Then
           Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
           Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`Redim Start(0,50)` makes the array dimensions `0 to 0, 0 to 50` i.e. a 2d array.

This means that when you call the array you need to provide parameters for both dimensions I.E: `Start(0,i)` or `Finish(0,i)`. Calling `Start(i)` will result in the error you mentioned.

The easiest way to get rid of the error is to change your Redim lines to

```
ReDim Start(50)
ReDim Finish(50)
```

which is what I assume you meant to do in the first place.

Note: Based upon the format you used, you may have been meaning to do `Start(0 to 50)` and `Finish(0 to 50)` initially. The comma in the dimensioning indicates another dimension instead of a separation between lower and upper bounds.

Comment: Thank you!  Well, that got rid of *that* error.   So I was pretty excited thinking I was finally done.  When my code finished executing, I found that my "hiding rows" code became un-done, if that makes sense.  So, when the code halted due to the above error, and I looked at the state of the spreadsheet, everything was as I wanted it to be, with the specific rows hidden.  Now, after the code finishes, the rows become "un-hidden."    Uggh.    I'll see what I can do before bothering everyone again...

Comment: Well, if you decide to "bother us"... It may help to put the code you're using in order. As you're explaining it, it looks like you might be populating the Array after you attempt to use it... and never actually using the array you populate. I'm saying this because snippet 3 goes before snippet 2. Also unless it's intolerably long, it may be beneficial to at least show us how Row is determined. When you step throw the code does `Cells(Row, 5).value = "Requirement"` happening? As written it looks like you may be only checking 1 row, as there's no loop around the row checking logic.

Comment: I've decided to bother you again, then.  So the logic that hid and un-hid rows did work when the code stopped for index errors (I looked at the spreadsheet - rows were hidden).  The indices were being calculated to determine the beginning and end of each subgroup and to build these formulas to count requirements in each subgroup.  These formulas did work accurately, too.  When I added another criteria to the countif formula, it crashed the formula (see another one of my questions...).  Now I have tried to move the hide/un-hide logice to the end of the code module.  Still... won't work.

Comment: Thanks for for your feedback.  I really do appreciate the helpful hints.

Comment: I can't help you, I don't know what's not working. Without seeing the code, it's almost impossible to know what the problem could be. I pointed out the problem in the code you listed, as for code you didn't list, I can only make wild guesses.

Comment: I posted the code and was told to thank the people who helped me.  I am very grateful to those who took the time and patience to read my questions and provide suggestions.  After I went back and thanked everyone, I deleted the post that had the entire code and explanations of the two main issues (and how I tried to solve them).

Comment: Ah, I was confused. I didn't realize you asked a new question. Anyway, the most typical way of thanking people on Stack Overflow is to either upvote their posts, or accept their answers correct. Since your issue is resolved I will not respond on here any longer. Glad you got it sorted.